# import moviepy error issue with python3.9+ and matplotlib on latest MacOS M1

Tags: matplotlib, ffmpeg, python-3.9, moviepy

For python 3.9+ there seems to be an error when I import moviepy after a pip install for moviepy with the correct command as per docs. I am trying an alternative to save animated plots from matplotlib from .gif format to .mp4 format, but matplotlib on MacOS (M1 chip) supports only .gif due to a lack of the "FFMpeg" process (which stays unresolved after pip installs as well). Any clue what to do here?

Repeat:

For python 3.9+ there seems to be an error when I import moviepy after a pip install for moviepy with the correct command as per docs. I am trying an alternative to save animated plots from matplotlib from .gif format to .mp4 format, but matplotlib on MacOS (M1 chip) supports only .gif due to a lack of the "FFMpeg" process (which stays unresolved after pip installs as well). Any clue what to do here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm still researching this, but i had the same problem. I saw a comment (looking for it again) that said there was no "wheel" for the arm version ffmpeg, perhaps because ffmpeg does not provide static builds for apple silicon. (https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-mac => https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/#remarks "I do not plan to provide native ffmpeg binaries for Apple Silicon ARM.")

Answer (score 0):

I'm still researching this, but i had the same problem: MoviePy fails to install ffmpeg.

I saw a comment (looking for it again) that said the install of ffmpeg via moviepy failed, because there was no "wheel" for the ARM version of ffmpeg. This may be because ffmpeg does not provide static builds for apple silicon.

https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-mac => https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/#remarks:

```
"I do not plan to provide native ffmpeg binaries for Apple Silicon ARM."
```

I think you will need to install ffmpeg manually. You can build from source, or there are a number of places you can get a static version of ffmpeg for apple silicon m1/m2. One example: https://www.osxexperts.net/

I built it myself, and set this environment variable in the run configuration: FFMPEG_BINARY=/tmp/ff/bin/ffmpeg

And it seems to be working for me.